# How to make VS2017 + IISExpress + ng serve provide the latest angular code?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've created ASP.NET core + Angular application and at some point the the debugging in VS2017 using IISExpress has stopped serving the current version of my angular code.

When start debugging in VS2017 it opens Google Chrome with url

http://localhost:53504/login

If I open the code file in

```
Developer tools -> Sources -> webpack:// -> . -> src
```

it is some really old version. I have no idea why it gets that and not the file stored in the disk and what I see in VS2017.

This has worked before.

If I check the port for ng serve from VS2017 Output window and open that url in chrome I can see the current version of the source.

> ng serve "--port" "52685"

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:52685, open your browser on http://localhost:52685/ **

How to make the url opened by F5 to have current version of my angular code?

I have restarted computer to make sure that porevious debug sessions are not active.

Here's my launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53504",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "NIS": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make it's simple for you. When you create a template using VS like this

[image]

You will see in the output of ASP.Net Core Web Server it will run one port for angular app and one port for asp.net core server like this

[image]

One port is 50207 for angular. And another port is 51171 for ASP.Net Core. So you just need to access to port 51171

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read my question again. When I access the correct port (in your case 51171) I somehow get old version of the angular code. Now I cloned my repository to other location and all works fine. But in my original local repo the angualar app is frozen to some moment in the past.

Comment: it's really hard for me because you dont show me the project structure and your code can you upload somewhere so I can take a look at

Comment: I understand but I can't do it because the code is not public. In addition it would not help because as I said evertyhing works in other local repository i cloned on same machine. The application served from the original local folder is somehow stuck in the past.